# Change Label Caption Color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly because my label caption forecolor remains "red"
given my code below. Hoping some could enlighten me with the below code. Thank you!!

```
Private Sub Userform_initialize()

Me.lbl1.caption = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").value, "0.00%"
Me.lbl2.caption = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").value, "0.00%"
.
.
.
        If Val(Me.lbl1.caption) < 85 Then
        Me.lbl1.forecolor = RGB(255,0,0,)
        Else
        Me.lbl1.forecolor = RGB(0,0,0)
    
    If Val(Me.lbl2.caption) < 85 Then
    Me.lbl2.forecolor = RGB(255,0,0,)
    Else
    Me.lbl2.forecolor = RGB(0,0,0)
    
    End If
    
    If Val(Me.lbl3.caption) < 85 Then
    Me.lbl3.forecolor = RGB(255,0,0,)
    Else
    Me.lbl3.forecolor = RGB(0,0,0)
    
    End If
    
    
        If Val(Me.lbl4.caption) < 85 Then
    Me.lbl4.forecolor = RGB(255,0,0,)
    Else
    Me.lbl4.forecolor = RGB(0,0,0)
    
    End If
```

However, the result is regardless the value, the forecolor remains red.

Comment: When you step through the code using F8 which lines are getting run?  What do you see with `Debug.Print Val(Me.lbl1.caption)` ?

Comment: No errors. However, If may lbl1 caption is 80% or 100% it doesn't change the forecolor. It remains as red.

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on your updated code. This works for me:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Userform_initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    UpdateLabel Me.lbl1, ws.Range("D3").Value
    UpdateLabel Me.lbl2, ws.Range("D4").Value
    UpdateLabel Me.lbl3, ws.Range("D5").Value
 
End Sub
    
'Update the label `lbl` with value `v` - set color
'  depending on value of `v`
Sub UpdateLabel(lbl As MSForms.Label, v)
    With lbl
        .Caption = Format(v, "0.00%")
        .ForeColor = IIf(v < 0.85, vbRed, vbBlack)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm but for this case. I dont have a textbox. I have 1-20 labels.

Comment: That's just an example.  How are you running the code you posted? What triggers it?

Comment: This is how I do it.. I f theres an easy way how to contruct my code. Maybe that is the trigger

Comment: codes updated!!